# django rest framework object permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I don't seem to be triggering the `has_object_permission` function.

```
class MyPermission(DefaultPermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_superuser

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return request.user == obj.submitter
```

Going to `mydomain.com/api/mymodel/100`, this should be considered accessing the object, correct? I am viewing object `100` here. Why isn't my `trace()` being picked up?

### View

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (MyPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

Comment: Are you sure that `has_permission` returned `True` during your test?

Comment: @zymud `has_permissions` does not return true, but that's the way I want it, right? The user can edit their own record, but the viewset of all records should not be available to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a DRF generic views `check_permissions(request)` is always called in every request since it is inside the dispatch method.

`check_permissions` method collects all the permissions from the permission classes and checks each permission. If any permission return false the method raises an exception.

So if your `has_permission` method returns false `has_object_permission` is not called.

`check_object_permissions(request, obj)` calls `has_object_permission` method on each permission class. It is called inside `get_object` method.

So the rule is if `has_permission` for all permission classes returns true then and only then `has_object_permission` is checked.

```py
class MyPermission(DefaultPermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # check if the request is for a single object
        if view.lookup_url_kwarg in view.kwargs:
            return True
        return request.user.is_superuser

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return request.user == obj.submitter
```

Comment: Very nice answer, what I've been trying to convey, you said it really simple.

Answer (score 1):

Permission won't work because check_object_permissions method is called only in get_object function. So you should call that function in your views:

```
def check(self, request, pk=None):
    obj = self.get_object()
```

Or you could add permissions directly in the decorator,

Example

```
    class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        ....
        permission_classes = (MyPermission, )


        @detail_route(methods=['GET', ])
        def custom(self, request, pk=None):
            my_obj = self.get_object() # do this and your permissions shall be checked
            return Response('whatever')
```

From the [docs(django-rest-framework)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

> **Note**: The instance-level has_object_permission method will only be called if the view-level has_permission checks have already passed. Also note that in order for the instance-level checks to run, the view code should explicitly call .check_object_permissions(request, obj). If you are using the generic views then this will be handled for you by default.

Comment: Where should `def check()` go?

Comment: check() was an example view, what you need to is, `obj = self.get_object()`, this function triggers the check_object_permissions(), or you could just call object.check_object_permissions()

Comment: I still don't understand. Where should `obj = self.get_object()` go? Inside `has_permission()`?

Comment: No, not inside permission... it should go inside the view, like `def view_name(re that's one way.
Or you could just set the permission_classes = (MyPermission,)

Comment: how about now? did you get what I m saying? sorry for the confusion

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. If I put `return True` in both `has_permissions` and `has_object_permission` then it passes. `False` in either one says not authorized.

Comment: I think that, you need has_object_permissions to be acted upon a queryset rather than an object, for your information, has_object_permissions as the name suggests checks the permission of a specific object, not a queryset.